# how to find the $BUNDLE_PATH for ruby on mac

Tags: ruby, lita

I'm trying to deploy lita to docker, I'm following the docker-lita guide but I have reached to this command

```
docker run -d --name lita --link redis --restart always -v $BUNDLE_PATH:/var/bundle -p 80:$LITA_HTTP_PORT $LITA_IMAGE_NAME
```

but i dont know where the `$BUNDLE_PATH`is on mac.  I'm using rbenv to manage my gems.
In the guide it states to "Replace $BUNDLE_PATH with the absolute path to the directory on the host machine where gems should be cached" but I don't know where that is.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docker-lita documentation](https://github.com/litaio/docker-lita):

> Replace $BUNDLE_PATH with the absolute path to the directory on the host machine where gems should be cached.

the `$BUNDLE_PATH` directory is a cache directory. You can then choose any directory on your host that is empty and that can be written to.

Comment: Oh I was thinking that it was the directory that house the Ruby gems when they are bundled

Comment: You can probably reuse an existing cache, but it's not mandatory.